# React app logs on Google App Engine says "Starting the development server..." and takes 30+ seconds to start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

I have deployed a React app to Google App Engine (using an F2 instance, nodejs16 runtime) and the start up is incredibly slow, at least 30 seconds. I've also noticed in the logs that it says "Starting the development server...", which seems bad because it's obviously in production.

Are the two things related? And, either way, should I be doing something so that a production server is being started? Before deploying, I did run `npm run build` and so the `build` folder has been included in the deployment

Comment: What do you have as your start script in your package.json?

Comment: @NoCommandLine thanks for the reply, it turns out I should've deployed just deployed the build files rather than the entire codebase

Comment: @OD1995, please post your answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I realised that I should only have deployed my build files to Google App Engine and not the entire codebase.

I also switched to Netlify from GAE because it was free.